# How are global functions defined in Swift?

Tags: function, swift, global

I wrote a simple function that displays an alert when it is called. I'd like to use this function in several viewControllers. Right now I have the same bit of code copy-pasted into the bottom of each viewController, but I can't help but think there's a better way.

How can one define a function that can be called from any viewController?

Just for reference I'll paste my function below, but this is a general question. I'd like to be able to find an eloquent way to handle keyboard management identically across all view controllers as well.

```
func displayAlert(title:String, error:String, buttonText: String) {

    // Create the alert
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    // Add an action
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonText, style: .Default, handler: { action in

        // Dismiss when the button is pressed
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }))

    // Add it to viewController
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Do you Find Any way to maintain all key board code in separate class.

Comment: I was able to put together a subclass of UIViewController that works alright. But it's a little bit hacky. I think a protocol would be the best way to do it, but when I tried redoing it that way recently I ran into compatability problems with adding NSNotificationCenter and Swift. Something about Cocoa being in Objective-C made it impossible to add observers.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Unless you declare the function as `private` or `fileprivate`, which limit the visibility to the file or scope where it is defined, you can use it anywhere in the module if declared as `internal` (the default), and also from external modules if declared as `public` or `open`.

However since you say that you need it in view controllers only, why not implementing it as an extension to the view controller?

```
extension UIViewController {
    func displayAlert(title:String, error:String, buttonText: String) {
        ...
    }
}
```